# Как отобразить на блок-схеме функцию?

Tags: python, функции, блок-схема

Вопрос понятен из заголовка. Собственно, вот код:

```
A = []


def adder():
    odd = 0
    even = 1
    for row in range(6):
        A.append([])
        for column in range(7):
            A[row].append(random.randint(0, 9))
        if row == odd:
            A[row].sort(reverse=True)
            odd += 2
        elif row == even:
            A[row].sort(reverse=False)
            even += 2
        print(A[row])


adder()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Есть код. Как составить его блок-схему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно в блок-схеме не получится отобразить функцию. Но можно сделать так: составить блок-схему функции и назвать её именем функции, потом составить ещё одну блок-схему, в которой данная функция вызывается.

Answer (score 0):

@vlados155
Сделал как понял. Верно?

[image: Блок-схема с функцией]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Да, в принципе. всё верно.